# In Pokemon Go, would it cost the same stardust and candies to Power Up if the Pokemon is evolved first or afterwards?

Tags: pokemon-go

Say if I have a Dragonair, and keep on using stardust and candies to power it up to the max, would it cost exactly the same amount of stardust and candies if I evolve it to Dragonite first, and then power up?

Comment: this isn't a duplicate, as that question is about max CP, while this question is about the total cost of stardust and candies

Comment: It's the same..

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Yes.

The cost in stardust and candies depends on your trainer level and the position on the arc behind the pokemon, not on what the pokemon is or how many times it has evolved.

The CP multiplier of evolving and the CP gain for powering up should also match so that the CP of a specific pokemon will be the same whether you power up and then evolve or evolve and then power up.

Comment: Stardust and candies required to power up a Pokemon are based on the Pokemon level, not the trainer level. A level 1 Pokemon will always cost 200 stardust and 1 candy, even if the trainer is level 40.

Comment: @Tester101 Yes, but the trainer level will affect the location on the arc of a given pokemon level, so if two pokemon are at the same spot on the arc but are owned by different trainers who are different levels, the cost to train will be different (because the pokemon would actually be different levels). And pokemon level is not a clearly defined stat from the player view.

Comment: you can make a close approximation of the Pokemon level, based on the amount of stardust required to power it up.

Comment: For example, if the cost to power up is 3000 stardust, the Pokemon must be level 21, 21.5, 22, or 22.5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it costs the same.

*However*, **do not** do this because your evolved pokemon might not have the most optimal moveset.

**Always** wait until you evolve your mons before powering them up. Some movesets can be as low as 50-60% as powerful as the optimal moveset.